# Injecting my UnitOfWork into my Repository Constructor

Tags: nhibernate, repository, structuremap

Im very new but on a quest to learn nhibernate and DI with structuremap so am making an app to test everything out.

I am having some problems injecting my unitofwork into my base repository. I create a unitofwork on every request then either commit or rollback at the end. But when tryin to inject into my base repository its always null when i go to use it in my methods. More specifically i get this error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". Any ideas what im doing wrong and if this is the correct route i should be going?

Many thanks in advance.

Base Repository:

```
public abstract class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
{
  public readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

  public Repository(IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork)
  {
    UnitOfWork = _unitOfWork;
  }

  public Repository() {}

  public void Save(T obj)
  {
    _unitOfWork.CurrentSession.Save(obj);
  }
}
```

StructureMap registry thats set in my application_start:

```
 public class NHibernateRegistry : Registry
 {
   public NHibernateRegistry()
   {
     For<IUnitOfWork>().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped().Use<UnitOfWork>();

     For<ISession>().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped().Use(context => context.GetInstance<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession());

     For<ISessionFactory>().Singleton().Use(NHibernateSessionFactory.GetSessionFactory());
   }
 }
```

Update:

The baserepository is inherited by specific repositorys ie ArticleRepository then im injecting that into my aspx pages on application_start. Then my aspx page inherits a basepage where the buildUp takes place. And i access the repository like this:

```
public IArticleRepository ArticleRepo { get; set; }

public void SaveThing()
{
    ArticleRepo.Save(object);
}
```

This gets called on application_start:

```
  public class Bootstrapper
  {
    public static void BootStrap()
    {
      ObjectFactory.Configure(x =>
      {
        x.AddRegistry<NHibernateRegistry>();
        x.AddRegistry<WebRegistry>();
      });
    }
  }
```

And in the webregistry:

```
For<IArticleRepository>().Use<ArticleRepository>();
```

Comment: How are you instantiating your repository?

Comment: @geepie thats how you are registering it, how do you "get" an instance of IArticleRepository in your .aspx page?

Comment: I would assume he's just doing var repository = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IArticleRepository>();

Comment: @geepie is Phill's comment true?

Comment: @mxmissle just updated the question. Thankyou both for your help so far im still at the stage where im asking a lot of questions hopefully it will all click soon enough.

Comment: So you never actually resolve an instance of IArticleRepository. Thats probably your issue.

Comment: So i need to do something like your above comment " ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IArticleRepository>();"? I currently do that at the start of every request for the UnitOfWork.

Comment: You need to resolve the repository, not the unit of work, StructureMap will inject an instance of the UoW into the repository for you. But you still need to tell StructureMap that you want the Repository.

Comment: OK, would you be able to point me in the right direction on how to do this? And would i need to do this for every type of repository ie UserRepository etc.

Comment: Well as a test, where you're calling save, try adding a line before it like "ArticleRepo = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IArticleRepository>();" if that works then we know your StructureMap stuff is setup and working correctly.

Comment: Hi Phill, did the above and i still have the same problem. I will update my question with the structuremap classes.

Comment: What happens if you get rid of the empty constructor on  your  abstract Repository class?

Comment: @mxmissile - good catch, I didn't see that. geepie, your ArticleRepository most likely doesn't contain a constructor taking ISession since you have your base repository with an empty constructor. Remove the empty constructor from the base, implement a constructor on your derived class passing the UoW into the base repository. "public ArticleRepository(IUnitOfWork uow) : base(uow){}"

Comment: @geepie - Just realized I wrote 'ISession' instead of 'IUnitOfWork' cant edit the comment tho.

Comment: @Phill Thats ok figured it out. Its working now with adding this: "public ArticleRepository(IUnitOfWork uow) : base(uow){}", although im still a bit confused about wiring generics up with structuremap. If you update your answer i will accept it. Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: @geepi - cool beans, glad it worked. Looks like Yads beat me to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a good chance your `ArticleRepository` doesn't have a constructor that takes an `IUnitOfWork` as a parameter make sure you have the following

```
public class ArticleRepository : Repository<Article>
{
    public ArticleRepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork) : base(unitOfWork)
    {
    }
...
}
```

Remember Strcuture map uses the greediest constructor on the class that it instantiates. Since your abstract repository class will never be instantiated it will not use its constructors. I would also suggest not having any default constructors if your classes need to have their dependencies injected that way. Less chance for errors that way.

Answer (score 1):

```
  public readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

  public Repository(IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork)
  {
    UnitOfWork = _unitOfWork;
  }
```

I think you mean to write

```
  public readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

  public Repository(IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork)
  {
    _unitOfWork = UnitOfWork;
  }
```

You were assigning the local variable to the parameter instead of the parameter to the local variable.

Edit: Also you should write your parameter with a lowercase U 'unitOfWork' instead of 'UnitOfWork'

Comment: Hi Phill, switched them round and i still have the same problem.

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint in the constructor to see if the UoW is being passed in?

Comment: Hi Phill, yeh i tried that and the breakpoint doesnt catch anything the debugger just goes straight to the _unitOfWork in the save method.